# Send KeyEvent from Service

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create an Android application that overlays a button on top of other applications, which when clicked triggers a 'Page Down' key event. This way one can easily scroll through e.g. a web page in any desired web browser.

I draw the button from a `Service`, using `WindowManager` and the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`-permission to draw over other apps. To send a `KeyEvent` to the currently focused window (like the web browser), I'd like to do something like the following in the `onClick` method:

```
BaseInputConnection  mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(targetView, true);
KeyEvent keyDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN);
KeyEvent keyUp = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(keyDown);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(keyUp);
```

The problem is that I think it is not possible to get the currently focused view (e.g. the web browser's window) from my `Service` context, which I need to provide as the `targetView` to the `BaseInputConnection`. Is that correct? Are there any other ways to trigger the key event? All I need to do is simulate a Page Down key press from e.g. a hardware keyboard.
I don't think declaring the app to be an InputMethod itself would be the way to go, would it?

Comment: What you want is not generally possible, for security reasons. You would need to implement an `AccessibilityService`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I see that `AccessiblityService' provides some 'global' actions like the Home and Back buttons. Do you know if one can use it to perform a Page Down event as well? As per the security - I thought if a keyboard can do it, why can't I do it? Even if I might have to go all the way of making a custom InputMethod (with just one button).

Comment: "Do you know if one can use it to perform a Page Down event as well?" -- AFAIK, an `AccessibilityService` can inject any key event. "I thought if a keyboard can do it, why can't I do it?" -- an app implementing an IME (input method editor, a.k.a. soft keyboard) has certain requirements from a security standpoint, and the user has to go through special steps to use it.